# Missing clicks from ExactTarget exported data

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have implemented a java program which our customers are using to pull data from their ExactTarget accounts. I am using ExactTarget Soap Api with Axis 2.0. The data is being pulled daily by doing a Data Extract Api request. However, one of the clients has been complaining about a few missing click events from the imported data from ET. So I re-pulled the data for that particular day that had the missing clicks, and the missing clicks were there. That is strange considering the fact that I used the same program as our client to pull the data. So is there any reasonable explanation why the clicks were missing when the data were pulled the same day as the click events happened, but they are present when I pull the data now?

Thanks,
Erisa

Comment: Can you comment on how soon you were pulling those missing clicks?  Clicks are not 100% real time, so they don't always post immediately.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I think we are pulling real time but need to confirm it with the guy that has done the automation process. Meanwhile, I checked the file with the clicks and saw that even though we had requested clicks from "11/16/2014 21:58:24 PM" to "11/17/2014 21:58:24 PM" the latest click we had was done at this time: 11/17/2014 3:59:32 PM 
So basically we are missing a whole interval of click within [3:59:32 PM, 21:58:24 PM]
@Timothy so when should we pull the data in order to be sure that all the events that happened during that time interval already are in the system?
Thanks!